# ¿Cómo obtener texto de una pagina web desde webbrowser en c#?

Tags: c#

Tengo un control webborwser en la que carga una pagina y deseo obtener datos de la tabla que muestra. Use este código y no muestra nada:

```
        HtmlDocument doc = WebBrowser1.Document;

        HtmlElementCollection col = doc.GetElementsByTagName("td");
        string t = "";
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in col)
        {
            t += elem.InnerText;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(t);
```

Tabla con datos que de quiere recuperar (parte seleccionada -y otro-)
[image: Tabla de datos]

Código de la tabla html (la parte seleccionada es el código del dato que se quiere obtener)
[image: Código html de la tabla]

Al ejecutar el código no muestra los datos que hay en la fila o de un campo en especifico que quisiera como el MONTO. Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar esto: (en prefix es su palabra) "venta-ultimos-movimientos"

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    result = client.DownloadString($"https://www.sitename.com/");
}

using (var reader = new StringReader(result))
{
    string line;
    do
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (line != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(prefix))
            {
                lstResult.Add(result);
            }
        }
    } while (line != null);
}
return lstResult;
```

Tengo un ejemplo en mi github

https://github.com/thiagoloureiro/SMSReceiver/blob/master/SMSReceiver/WebClientReader.cs

Comment: ESto funciona, siempre y cuando este todo en la misma linea.. y si la pagina viene con un enter entre el prefijo y el dato?

Answer (score -1):

Yo utilizo una librería llamada [ScrapySharp](https://bitbucket.org/rflechner/scrapysharp/wiki/Home) para acceder al contenido de las páginas web. Si quieres profundizar mas en el tema, te recomiendo leer esta [serie de artículos](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1041115/Webscraping-with-Csharp). En mi caso la uso para obtener imagenes y contenido de tablas. Es es el [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ScrapySharp) para instalarla.

```
ScrapingBrowser browser = new ScrapingBrowser();
WebPage pagina= browser.NavigateToPage(new Uri(sitioWeb));
string contenidoHMTL= pagina.Html.InnerHtml;
```

Comment: ¿Por qué el negativo? De cualquier manera, espero le sirva al OP, no he tenido problemas con la funcionalidad de esta librería.